# Can't see my programmatically added textviews in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've added 2 textviews in ConstrainLayout in code, but i can't see them. 
The screen is empty.
Please can anybody help me to figure out this?
Thanks a lot!

```
public class ActivitySixth extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv3;
    private ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
    private static final int ID_CONS_LAY = 160;
    private static final int ID_TV1 = 160;
    private static final int ID_TV3 = 160;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sixth);

        mConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_Constraint);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(mConstraintLayout);

        tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv3 = new TextView(this);

       tv1.setText("TextView number ONE");
       tv3.setText("TextView number THREE");

       tv1.setId(ID_TV1);
       tv3.setId(ID_TV3);

       mConstraintLayout.addView(tv1);
       mConstraintLayout.addView(tv3);

       set.connect(tv1.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.parent_Constraint, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
       set.connect(tv3.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.parent_Constraint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
       set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
}
```

}

Comment: why giving same id?

Comment: oh, good,question

Comment: Not Only Question, may be your answer bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `ID`s should be different, second, you need to add constraints to the `TextView`s' width/height:

```
    set.connect(tv1.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.parent_Constraint, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
    set.constrainWidth(tv1.getId(), WRAP_CONTENT);
    set.constrainHeight(tv1.getId(), WRAP_CONTENT);
    set.connect(tv3.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.parent_Constraint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    set.constrainWidth(tv3.getId(), WRAP_CONTENT);
    set.constrainHeight(tv3.getId(), WRAP_CONTENT);
    set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
```

By the way, to avoid conflicts, you can define ids using resources xml.

1. create `ids.xml` inside your res\values folder
2. define ids:

   ```
   <resources>
       <item type="id" name="textView1" />
   </resources>
   ```
3. use the defined id:

   ```
   R.id.textView1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please follow below code

```
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
    layout.addView(view, 0);
    set.clone(layout);
    set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 60);
    set.applyTo(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView contactUs = new TextView(this);
contactUs.setText(R.string.contactus);
contactUs.setTextSize(25);
contactUs.setId(R.id.contactUs);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams clpcontactUs = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
contactUs.setLayoutParams(clpcontactUs);

constraintLayout.addView(contactUs);

ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(mConstraintLayout);

set.connect(tv1.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.parent_Constraint, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
set.connect(tv3.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.parent_Constraint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
```

try something like this..

ref. http://www.zoftino.com/adding-views-&-constraints-to-android-constraint-layout-programmatically